# Calling PowerShell Get-SPContentDatabase in C#

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to use the Get-SPContentDatabase powershell command from a code behind file:

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {             
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-SPContentDatabase -site http:////gBox.contoso.com");
            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke(); 

            if (PSOutput.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
                {                      
                    if (outputItem != null)
                    {
                        lblResults.Text += outputItem.BaseObject.ToString();
                        lblResults.Text += outputItem.BaseObject.GetType().FullName;
                        lblResults.Text += "<hr>";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblResults.Text = "No output found";
            }

        }
```

However, the PSOutput keeps coming back with zero objects.

The Command works great from the PowerShell window, but not from the code behind.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The command `Get-SPContentDatabase` is failed to execute since `Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` module have to be loaded first:

```
using (var psInst = PowerShell.Create())
{
    psInst.AddScript("Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell");
}
```

Example: print ContentDb names

```
using (var psInst = PowerShell.Create())
{
    psInst.AddScript("Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell");
    psInst.AddScript("Get-SPContentDatabase -site http://contoso.intranet.com/");
    var result = psInst.Invoke();
    foreach (var outputItem in result)
    {
        var contentDb = outputItem.BaseObject as SPContentDatabase;
        Console.WriteLine(contentDb.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a good suggestion, but using your exact code, I still get null in the result variable.

Comment: Btw, please make sure to specify proper site Url for Get-SPContentDatabase command

Comment: Do you think it might have something to do with Permissions?

Comment: Probably, you could run VS as a user who does not have access to SharePoint